# Refactoring JavaScript/TypeScript: Eliminating repeated code blocks

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement, refactoring

How can I shorten this monster block? (Non-Array solution)

```
setFooTypeFlag(flag: string) {
  switch (flag) {
    case 'a':
      this.fooType.a = true;  
      this.fooType.b = false;
      this.fooType.c = false;
      this.fooType.d = false;
      break;
    case 'b'
      this.fooType.a = false;
      this.fooType.b = true;
      this.fooType.c = false;
      this.fooType.d = false;
      break;
    case 'c':
      this.fooType.a = false;
      this.fooType.b = false;
      this.fooType.c = true;
      this.fooType.d = false;
      break;
    case 'd':
      this.fooType.a = false;
      this.fooType.b = false;
      this.fooType.c = false;
      this.fooType.d = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it short enough for you? :)

Basically, iterate on each key and just set everything to `flag === key` :)

```
setFooTypeFlag(flag: string) {
  Object.keys(this.fooType).forEach(key => {
      this.fooType[key] = flag === key;
  });
}
```

If at the beginning, `this` has no keys yet, please refer to the [answer of Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55395858/5860648).

Comment: Sorry @JonasWilms - what would `this` refer to above? (I'm still not entirely clear about lexical `this`).

Comment: @jack the same `this` as in `setFooTypeFlag`

Answer (score 3):

Use a dynamic property name. This will work for any amount of possibilities, and it doesn't require you to initialise them all beforehand:

```
setFooTypeFlag(flag: string) {
  var chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    this.fooType[chars[i]] = chars[i] == flag;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you Jack, the real implementation is not so easy in the code above, there are some function calls and assignments. Therefore I've thought, there is maybe a known pattern as grouped radio buttons work. I need an array-free solution, like to try lodash etc.

Comment: You can replace the if-else with `this.fooType[chars[i]] = chars[i] == flag`

Comment: @Lonely for the code shared in the question, this is the correct solution.

Comment: @adiga & Jack: the answer by sjahan is more elegant

Comment: @Lonely if there are properties other than `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, they will also be set to boolean

Comment: @JonasWilms do you mean the lexical `this`, or the general code layout?

Answer (score 0):

```
enum fooTypes {
  "a" = "a",
  "b" = "b",
  "c" = "c",
  "d" = "d"
}

interface IFooFlags {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}

const defaultFooTypes = new Map<fooTypes, boolean>([
  [fooTypes.a, true],
  [fooTypes.b, true],
  [fooTypes.c, true],
  [fooTypes.d, true]
]);

const fooTypesMappings = new Map<fooTypes, boolean[]>([
  [fooTypes.a, [true, false, false, false]],
  [fooTypes.b, [false, true, false, false]],
  [fooTypes.c, [false, false, true, false]],
  [fooTypes.d, [false, false, false, true]]
]);

class MyClass {
  private mappings = fooTypesMappings;
  private fooTypes = defaultFooTypes;

  private setFooTypes(values: boolean[]): void {
    [...this.fooTypes.keys()].forEach((key, index) =>
      this.fooTypes.set(key, values[index])
    );
  }

  // In modern engines you can return:
  // Object.fromEntries(this.fooTypes)
  public getFooTypes(): IFooFlags {
    return [...this.fooTypes].reduce(
      (obj, { 0: key, 1: val }) => ({ ...obj, [key]: val }),
      {}
    );
  }

  public setFooTypeFlag(flag: fooTypes): void {
    const flagTypes = this.mappings.get(flag);
    if (!flagTypes) {
      throw new Error("Invalid flag type");
    }
    this.setFooTypes(flagTypes);
  }
}

const fooLover = new MyClass();
fooLover.setFooTypeFlag(fooTypes.d);
alert(JSON.stringify(fooLover.getFooTypes()));
```

[Here is a demo of it](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAZg9nAKgTwA7AM5QN4CgpQBEAhoVALxGkA0+RARmZYY7QYQMZNFdtEAm3QoNwBfXLgCWIAC7AATjGIdgUAJIAxBBoA2xAOZY8BANoBrYMgBcUDDPnT9AXRv0EO4MRABuMRI5wIHZQ-MBKYDoyWkhomBRQIMAA7lAAssSoADzwMegY1FBucB5eAHwAFCZ0JjkoeQB0xAX2YMBOfDUIdZj19M3yre3VtbEY9Rz9gx0jDfyTbbhOAJS+uAFBMrBdo+moqI5YlIkpu9nbeQVFJSAmThVVpjM9TVAmLcAFSjoYH7DE378vj8nENHucen1XkDfu9Pv8fnCASDpuCxhMofDAZj5ojgaCoaj6nMMQDcVjSVB3iDFit-HoMFhUsgAML0ox0VAOABuxDkUAgGX2IEM8SeGF2QsMvgInMkPL5YvioXCkWi3Qwqxl3N5qh+UVR5R5OlaGFc7k8N2WNi5cEk-BwdFM9WdMgAFpIxmL6hZkBhyksnPV4PIAKLKV3lco+grSUIADyWFFKjoIlPdnsJeqjlgKRpNJljwDjyxTtII4joAHpK+oQPy4KF5HXQPppHFkHAwFAOF4oPJgDIwE2rFWawB5egAK2AHBkQfkcAgIdkDkw5TdHqDqKWHLA9B0kg4UH0A7Vo39Nk02j0IuMqf7g6br2d9Q3GdymED-f4YBU5RTBDlHAU4FNgUAAAw2NGUAAIzWv8UCiIm5ClFA5RgS+wGTgU5iWC4UBGohSx8KmODiKRZaIRIMp7geR56me6C6AY5QwDeNhiks1q2vad4EOswRsQY6rxG+9QCnsBz1CeMisTelEEJIMBoQAhEJ+jqomfGpm6C4pMcUAhvIC7yOUhBqCARp2rAN6UrEhAKVRpFiQxBrqZp0pURWAmbDkAAycBcgo8QGUyrLEAy-q+P5gUKPUrkfsx+isYS-C0v8CiyQAUgAymOABy8X2I4SnIClcABUF8jSaeBpLPV3hAA)

Answer (score 0):

I also got inspired by the answer from @jack-bashford:

```
class MyClass {
  private flags = [...Array(26)].map((_, i) => (i + 10).toString(36));
  private minObjectKeys = 4;

  public buildBaseObject(flag: string): any {
    return this.getFlagPortion(flag).reduce(
      (obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: key === flag }),
      {}
    );
  }

  private getFlagPortion(flag: string): string[] {
    const sliceEndPositon = this.getSliceEndPosition(flag);
    return this.flags.slice(0, sliceEndPositon);
  }

  private getSliceEndPosition(flag: string): number {
    const flagPosition = this.flags.indexOf(flag) + 1;
    return flagPosition < this.minObjectKeys
      ? this.minObjectKeys
      : flagPosition;
  }
}

const fooLover = new MyClass();
alert(JSON.stringify(fooLover.buildBaseObject("d")));
```

[Here is the demo](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oAcBOAlgG5gAuAptAGbgDmMAvNANoB07AgnnmPABQAmAGwBKALqsAtmBx8+AfQA00AiOgMAfND4FoAamgBGAAwjWpAPYBlUoQB2tPgGZRIgNxZchEhWiSCdgDyAEYAVuTApADS5PCM0AAsHp44AK7BIATA0MGpBCAAJgBCkOQh4ZF8NGC0AFzQELYBtCL1YHbw6J7YeOSkqXh20KQAFgQQrLR9AGJ0AAoWeKQEFnZVdGa9BanA5Hzd2NoWYcoA1rFqmtpo0Oysx6HKzOfwYvUv6gxM1bTQAL4iRQHbBoP4HdyeMEpbxkShTUizGoLJYrNY-eqNewtDFNBzMMRdQ7QYCrRoNTK7ACidgKCwgBEsQyYo3Gkz6Vgp5GptIs9OWq3WNQhRN6-UGwzGEx+EwgnL4xmUsqyXJpdIZq2F-ww0OIsOg8I5yu5av5aLoOKxrWgdlSkmC5DwhMOJLsZJ+JtR6glrOlrACBXIAA9AlRBS19EYPCK+gMhu7eQzPQAeb0TfxBMIRaKxCDA6AAflTUgC5SzMTiefq8b5qKjWqhLrdFgsABkLEQHV67OQAO5wJAoCB8CFgEAO0h8ABSVkCADlWJjmgQqPwqM22x28KxcvliqVS5UAEQFQ8iM8eIA)